# Is it possible to inject JavaScript into the currently loaded page from the Chrome Developer Tools window?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to add a panel UI to the Chrome devtools window and display some information about the currently loaded page.
To get the information, I want to inject some JavaScript code before the page is loaded, so that I can change the behavior of some methods.

I tested with the following code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test Dev Panel",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Extends the Developer Tools, replacing Array.toString() with a bogus one.",
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["bogusarray.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }]
}
```

devtools.js

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("Text Dev Panel",
                          "img/iconDev.png",
                          "panel.html");
```

bogusarray.js

```
Array.prototype.toString = function () {
    return 'Injected!';
  };
```

However, as the behavior of Array.toString() does not change, the JavaScript (bogusarray.js) seems never injected into the loaded pages.
Is there any advice on this?

Comment: You might could set a breakpoint in the first line of the script, edit it and continue...

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, I would like to post this as answer so future readers find the solution quickly.

Comment: Do you mean the breakpoint problem? Yes, I added a line break in the first line and removed the hyphen from the file names so everything worked. (it seems impossible to insert code into a list.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your injected script bogusarray.js does not script the page - it runs is a separate execution context and can only see the page's DOM. You could script the page via injecting a `<script>` tag into DOM from your content script, but it will still be too late to override functions like Array's prototype.

To achieve your goal, you should reload inspected page from within your DevTools extension using `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload()`. Just pass your overrides using `injectedScript` parameter into it.

Comment: It works and now I can override Array's prototype. However, if I try to retrieve the page's variables via postMessage, the page crashes with "Aw Snap". It might be a security restriction, but I will post a separate question about it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Would you please take a look at the related issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196480/calling-chrome-devtools-inspectedwindow-reload-with-injection-causes-aw-snap

Comment: This sounds great but could you provide an example as how to pass an override into chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload().  ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

- set a breakpoint in the first line of the script
- edit the script
- continue debugging