# Calling chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload with injection causes Aw Snap

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to create a tool that monitors the usage of some JavaScript APIs in web pages. My plan is to override the JavaScript API's, store the call information into a global variable, and then send it to content script via postMessage. However, injecting code something like below into the web page causes an "Aw Snap" error.

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("Test Dev Panel",
  "icon.png",
  "panel.html",
  function (panel) {
    var code = [ 
        "window.counter = 0;",
        "Array.prototype.push = function () {",
          "window.counter++;",
        "}",
        "window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {",
          "window.postMessage('Array.push() has been called ' + window.counter + ' times.', '*');",
        "}, false);"
      ];

    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload({
      injectedScript: code.join('')
    });
...
  });
```

It might be a security restriction. But is there any way to achieve my goal?

--- Update ---
The error doesn't occur if I remove the postMessage() call.
Also, it doesn't if I remove the Array.prototype overriding code.
It seems to me that calling the postMessage() and overwriting Array's prototype at the same time are causing the error.

Comment: This isn't relevant any more, but you need a ; before the window.addEventListener line. "};" rather than "}"

Comment: Aha! It was just a syntax error...

Comment: Anyway, thank you for pointing this out Jono!

Comment: Don't suppose you could help with my issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440850/how-to-extract-the-loaded-javascript-files-from-dev-tools-extension

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error after the Array.prototype.push.

You need to end the line with a semicolon.

```
...
var code = [ 
        "window.counter = 0;",
        "Array.prototype.push = function () {",
          "window.counter++;",
        "};", //<-- Here
        "window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {",
          "window.postMessage('Array.push() has been called ' + window.counter + ' times.', '*');",
        "}, false);"
      ];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
"window.counter = 0;",
"Array.prototype.push = function () {",
"window.counter++;",
"}",
"window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {",
"window.postMessage('Array.push() has been called ' + window.counter + ' times.', '*');",
"}, false);"
```

code, i am not sure what you want to achieve!!

I hope you are aware of the fact Counter is always zero in a frame unless closes the window!

Comment: The API reference states that "If specified, the script will be injected into every frame of the inspected page immediately upon load, before any of the frame's scripts."

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#method-reload

It actually works as stated when I remove the postMessage call.